# JQuery change event only fire when the page is not fully loaded and fail to fire when page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My webpage that uses quite a number of jquery scripts, I am pre-populating my location field based on the input in the state input field and am using some some of alert to ensure that the on change event fires. However i noticed that the event only fires while the web page is loading and not after the page is completely loaded.

this are the URL's :
http://mmarket.vas2nets.com/request.php
and http://mmarket.vas2nets.com/register.php

Am guessing there is some confliction in my scripts, any help will be appreciated.

NOTE: Please do not mind my long script, It's to enable a through look at it.

```
<head>
//load the jquery script and test the function.    
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("div.span3 #state").change(function(){

 var data = $("div.span3 #state").serialize();
alert(data);
   $.ajax({

       url  : 'populateLocation.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : data,
       success:function(data){
                $('#location').html(data)
               }
    })


   });

});

</script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">
<section class="container">
<div class="dynamicContent">

<div class="inner">
<div class="row">
<div class="span8 offset2">
<header>
<h2>Provider's Registration</h2>
</header>
<div>
<div>
<div class="outside">
<div class="">
<div>

<div class="row">
<div class="span3  offset1">
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt>m</dt>
<dd>
<p>M-Market</p>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-link">more<span></span></a></p>
</dd>

</dl>
</div>
<div class="span3">

<form name="register" id="register" method="post" class="form_login" action="">
<label name="username">NAME</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<label name="phone">MOBILE NUMBER</label>
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value =='2348XXXXXXXX' ) 
this.value=''"     onblur="if(this.value=='') 
this.value='2348XXXXXXXX'"  value="2348XXXXXXXX" name="phone"/>
<label name="password">PASSWORD</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<label name="password2">RETYPE PASSWORD</label>
<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2"/>
<label>SERVICE</label>
<select name="provider" id="provider">
<option value="">Select Your Service</option>
<?php echo $service_fields; ?>
</select>
<label>STATE</label>
<select  id ="state" name="state">
<option value='0'>--- SELECT STATE------</option>
<?php echo $state_fields; ?>
</select></div>
<label>LOCATION</label>enter code here
<select id='location'> </select>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}); fires when the DOM is ready, but not nevesarily when everything is finished loading. $(window).load(function(){}); fires when everything is loaded.

Comment: Tips for the future include only the relevant part of your script.

Comment: I have tried to use $(window).load(function(){}); and its no longer working at all, bur with document.ready the event fire if I change the state while the page is still loading

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).load()` rather than `$(document).ready()` for the components that require the page be loaded.

It's perfectly reasonable to do this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  // code that requires the page to be loaded

});

$(document).ready(function() {

  // other code

});
```

`$(window).load()` waits for all elements including images, while `$(document).ready()` only waits for basic DOM elements.

Comment: I tried your advice it's not working, I thought it hard to do with code conflicting, but now I don't even know.. can you visit the page and help to see

Comment: @Hiroyalty I think in your case, the best thing to do would be to hide things that you don't want seen initially with CSS. The js is likely being loaded last (as it should be), so let your CSS do the hiding at first. JS can show hidden elements. Simply do a `display: none` on the elements you want hidden on page load